# Vue js bind event to dynamic child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

In jQuery I can bind event to dynamically created child element:

`$(staticAncestors).on(eventName, dynamicChild, function() {});`

For example, I have table and want to append new row, when user places focus in the last row input:

```
$("#meta-panel").on("focus", ".input-row:last input", function (event)   {
    myVueApp.addMetaInputRow(); //pushes new row into array
});
```

How can I achieve this with Vue?

Answer (score 2):

your new html is required to be compiled bu vue to behave like part of vue instace.

```
myVueApp = new Vue({
  methods: {
    addMetaInputRow: function(){
      // here you can add method which can focus on last row       
      var $element = $('#app').append('<div onClick="dynamic()">HTML code.</div>')
      this.$compile($element.get(0));
    },
    dynamic() {
      // add new elements to rows
      console.log('hello from dynamic content.')
    }
  }
});
```